# How can I define an event of TImer in a class?

Tags: c#

I creat a class with a variable of timer.I want to declare its `tick` event ,allowing other class use the event.How can I do that?

```
Class a
{
    protected System.Windows.Forms.Timer bindTimer;
}
```

Comment: In Visual Studio, type `bindTimer.Tick +=` and then tab through the prompts.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this:

```
class a
{
  protected System.Windows.Forms.Timer bindTimer;

  public event EventHandler OnTimer;

  private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    OnTimer(sender, e);
  }

  public a()
  {
    bindTimer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
  }
}
```